# Restricting certain printers to certain programs

Tags: windows, networking, firefox, network-printer

At my place of business, we use desktop PCs as Point-of-Sale units as well as workstations. We have two networked laser printers (standard letter size) in the office as well as receipt printers at each POS, which are also networked.

The issue we have is that when we print a .pdf file from Firefox, from an email for example, the employee will select one of the laser printers. Our POS software is web-based...so when they go to print the next receipt after a sale, the session default printer will be set to the laser printer - printing receipts to the laser printer and wasting paper.

I've given up asking employees to check what printer they're printing to before hitting a receipt (and honestly I understand - in a busy time, it is tedious and you forget, with the muscle-memory of hitting enter right away after clicking the print button) I want to find a way to prevent Firefox from printing to the network printers.

My first inkling is to block traffic from Firefox to the IP address of the printer, but I was wondering if there was an easier way. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It seems odd to me that them picking a printer for one-time use in a program would cause it to become the default printer. Perhaps you could expend on what you mean by "session"?  The user's Windows logon session, or the web-app session?

Comment: Windows logon session - closing and restarting Firefox doesn't do anything, but restarting the computer resets firefox to using the default printer for the system (which is the receipt printer for each POS). Try it yourself - print something from firefox to a non-default printer, and then print to a different printer.

Comment: Side note, I did post in Mozilla forums ages ago when I first ran into the problem and most people said "check your system default" or "tell your employees to be smarter lol" like I was an idiot.

Comment: So the actual Windows "Default printer" doesn't get changed? If it's specific to FF, why not use an alternative browser that doesn't do that?  Back to FF: are you using the FF's inbuilt PDF viewer? If you disable it and use Adobe Reader (or alike) instead, does it perform the same way with the printers?

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: Eh, kinda sorta. That's there to distinguish us from SF, but this is still in ewok country. The software in question, and the hardware is probably something anyone might have, and the fact that its corporate is just background. I'd *discourage* close votes in this case, and I'd suspect that if this was moved to SF, it would be kicked back here.

Comment: @DavidPostill As long as the person asking the question has full rights to the systems in question, the environment doesn't matter.  Firefox and network printers aren't corporate-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox ignores which printer is the default in Windows, and instead uses whichever was last selected in Firefox.

This behavior can be disabled by typing `about:config` in the address bar and changing the `print.save_print_settings` preference to `false`.  You might also have to clear the `print_printer` preference (or right-click and `reset`).

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for a helpful answer. I will test this and see if it works!

Comment: @CraigCollins I verified that this works.  Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer.